# Is there any thing you can do if you can't pay for a SSL certificate

Tags: facebook, ssl

Hello I am a hobbies developer and I don't make money of my app/website, I only have it to give out my work to FB users for free [My APP](http://apps.facebook.com/sifonick/)

I can't afford to pay the £30-40-50 for a SSL certificate and I think it is a little unfair that FB will be forcing you to use SSL.

My question is there any way I can get a free certificate or can FB provide me with one?

Hope there is some way around this as I don't want my app going down.

Kind Regards

Sifonick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try http://www.startssl.com/. you can get a free certificate for your domain and subdomain for free, and it is accepted by browsers automatically

Comment: "Mozilla and Google decided to distrust all StartCom root certificates as of 21st of October"

Comment: You can take a look at AWS ACM Service. It allows you to provision free SSL certificates for your domain. Here is a blog post I came across which can help you setup: https://www.intellyzen.com/free-https-certificates-aws/

Answer (score 0):

If you search around you will find a few sites that provide free SSL certificates. While these are generally not as widely accepted, it's certainly an alternative option and a step up from generating your own completely unaccepted certificate [which you can also do].

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem:

Not sure if free cloud service is a solution (a link offering info on this is displayed when you edit your FB app settings. hxxps://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/558/ )

Another CA hxxp://www.affirmtrust.com/free-ssl-certificate-products.html has announced they will be offering free certs for 3 years. Not up and running yet but I believe iminent and you you can pre-register.

No one else has mentioned it so I could be wrong, but I think you will also need an additional IP addres for https. ($30/£20 p.a. ?)

My web host provides a shared server for ssl/https - its free as part of my package - your package may include similar. As you are sharing it you may have to refer to it by a different domain e.g. hxxps://servername.sec.example.com/~accntid/index.html. This means both abs & rel links in your pages will require modification.  As the server is shared  "document root" is above "~accntid" in the example so server script references to the "doc root" will have to be altered.

HTH

Comment: Ted S mentioned hxxp://social-server.com/index/ ; it may be a solution for your need. But, I checked it out a few weeks ago and got the impression it was for apps appearing on Facebook Pages only. Checked again & under "Does Social Server have any limitations?" on its Info page - it also states "Suitable for Apps that don't require OAuth".

Answer (score -1):

I had the same question and came across [this site.](http://social-server.com/index/)  Seems to get the job done.

Edit:  Oh, did I mention it's free and instant?